# Creating a DER formatted ECDSA signature from raw r and s

Tags: c, openssl, digital-signature

I have a raw ECDSA signature: R and S values. I need a DER-encoded version of the signature. Is there a straightforward way to do this in openssl using the c interface?

My current attempt is to use `i2d_ECDSA_SIG(const ECDSA_SIG *sig, unsigned char **pp)` to populate an `ECDSA_SIG*`. The call returns non-zero but the target buffer doesn't seem to be changed.

I'm intiailly filling my ECDSA_SIG wtih `r` and `s` values. I don't see any errors. The man page says r and s should be allocated when I call `ECDSA_SIG_new`

```
ECDSA_SIG* ec_sig = ECDSA_SIG_new();

if (NULL == BN_bin2bn(sig, 32, (ec_sig->r))) {
  dumpOpenSslErrors();
 }
DBG("post r  :%s\n", BN_bn2hex(ec_sig->r));

if (NULL == BN_bin2bn(sig + 32, 32, (ec_sig->s))) {
  dumpOpenSslErrors();
 }
DBG("post s  :%s\n", BN_bn2hex(ec_sig->s));
```

S and R are now set:

`post r  :397116930C282D1FCB71166A2D06728120CF2EE5CF6CCD4E2D822E8E0AE24A30` 
`post s  :9E997D4718A7603942834FBDD22A4B856FC4083704EDE62033CF1A77CB9822A9`

now to make the encoded signature.

```
int sig_size = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(ec_sig, NULL);
if (sig_size > 255) {
  DBG("signature is too large wants %d\n", sig_size);
 }
DBG("post i2d:%s\n", BN_bn2hex(ec_sig->s));
```

s hasn't changed:

`post i2d:9E997D4718A7603942834FBDD22A4B856FC4083704EDE62033CF1A77CB9822A9`

At this point I have more than enough bytes ready and I set the target to all 6s so it's easy to see what changes.

```
unsigned char* sig_bytes = new unsigned char[256];
memset(sig_bytes, 6, 256);

sig_size = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(ec_sig, (&sig_bytes));
DBG("New size %d\n", sig_size);
DBG("post i2d:%s\n", BN_bn2hex(ec_sig->s));

hexDump("Sig ", (const byte*)sig_bytes, sig_size);
```

The new size is 71
`New size 71` and s iis stiill the same:

```
  `post i2d:9E997D4718A7603942834FBDD22A4B856FC4083704EDE62033CF1A77CB9822A9`
```

The hex dump is all 6s.

```
  --Sig --  
  0x06:   0x06:   0x06:   0x06:   0x06:   0x06:   0x06:   0x06: 
  0x06:   ...
```

The dump is still all 6s even though the call didn't return 0. What am I missing tying to DER encode this raw signature?

Comment: I put together a test and I'm not getting 6s back in the output.  Can you post a MCVE?

Comment: what's an MCVE? I think the allocation of sig_bytes is the problem. Openssl is allocating the buffer for me and writing the resulting address into my buffer not the data itself. 
unsigned char* sig_bytes = new unsigned char[256];
memset(sig_bytes, 6, 256);

Comment: A [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I'm not sure that the problem is with the allocation of the buffer, but seeing a standalone example that anyone can run to demonstrate the problem would help.

Comment: *I need a DER-encoded version of the signature* - which kind of format do you need? There are several...

Comment: @mkl: One that works with a call to EVP_VerifyFinal. dbush fix got me going, **pp is an out-param. I should have noticed but a note about having to free it in the docs would have been helpful.

Comment: Update: since 1.1.0 in 2016 you can no longer directly access fields like ec_sig->r (i.e. the API is 'opaque'), and more importantly if you switch to the `_get0_` functions the ECDSA_SIG r and s fields are no longer allocated by `_new`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i2d_ECDSA_SIG` modifies its second argument, increasing it by the size of the signature.  From ecdsa.h:

```
/** DER encode content of ECDSA_SIG object (note: this function modifies *pp
 *  (*pp += length of the DER encoded signature)).
 *  \param  sig  pointer to the ECDSA_SIG object
 *  \param  pp   pointer to a unsigned char pointer for the output or NULL
 *  \return the length of the DER encoded ECDSA_SIG object or 0
 */
int   i2d_ECDSA_SIG(const ECDSA_SIG *sig, unsigned char **pp);
```

So you need to keep track of the original value of `sig_bytes` when you call `i2d_ECDSA_SIG`:

```
int sig_size = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(ec_sig, NULL);
unsigned char *sig_bytes = malloc(sig_size);
unsigned char *p;
memset(sig_bytes, 6, sig_size);

p = sig_bytes;
new_sig_size = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(_sig, &p);

// The value of p is now sig_bytes + sig_size, and the signature resides at sig_bytes
```

Output:

```
30 45 02 20 39 71 16 93 0C 28 2D 1F CB 71 16 6A
2D 06 72 81 20 CF 2E E5 CF 6C CD 4E 2D 82 2E 8E
0A E2 4A 30 02 21 00 9E 99 7D 47 18 A7 60 39 42
83 4F BD D2 2A 4B 85 6F C4 08 37 04 ED E6 20 33
CF 1A 77 CB 98 22 A9
```

Comment: Yeah. I kept the initial pointer to sig_bytes and the call changed it. The printout I was making wasn't what actually the changed data, which was lost when the temporary variable went away. I've got your MVCE but I don't think we actually need it any longer. The double pointer should have been a clue that they were allocating things for me rather than asking me to do so.