# How to convert and verify ECDSA binary signature using OpenSSL library?

Tags: c, openssl, ecdsa

I am trying to validate a signature returned by DS28C36 using OpenSSL in Linux. For testing purpose, I copied pasted public key and signature into global arrays. For signature conversion I followed this old post: [Creating a DER formatted ECDSA signature from raw r and s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390784/creating-a-der-formatted-ecdsa-signature-from-raw-r-and-s)
However, when I converted it using i2d_ECDSA_SIG, it only return 2 bytes for some reasons and of course the following ECDSA_verify failed. In addition, when I tried to dump it using BN_bn2hex, I got a segmentation fault. I am not sure what I did wrong here.

Thanks for your help

This is my test code

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>

#include <openssl/obj_mac.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/ecdsa.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

unsigned char rom_id[] = {0x4c, 0x51, 0xb7, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xfa};

unsigned char man_id[] = {0x00, 0x80};

unsigned char pub_key_raw[] = { 0x04, 
0x34, 0xe3, 0x12, 0x1d, 0x73, 0xc4, 0x25, 0x68, 0xef, 0xf8, 0xcc, 0x89, 0xc7, 0x77, 0x9c, 0x4e,
0x16, 0xe7, 0x79, 0xd5, 0x76, 0x68, 0x0e, 0xff, 0xad, 0x1f, 0x53, 0xd6, 0x33, 0x70, 0xb8, 0xa3,
0xa5, 0xb9, 0x92, 0xc9, 0x3c, 0x75, 0xf7, 0x07, 0xbf, 0xed, 0xe1, 0x25, 0xbf, 0x1f, 0xcb, 0xeb,
0x30, 0x57, 0x4f, 0x05, 0x96, 0x28, 0x9f, 0x66, 0x33, 0x7a, 0x46, 0xb6, 0x76, 0x35, 0x8c, 0xdd};

unsigned char challenge[] = {0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc};

unsigned char usr_page3[] = {
                   0xB6, 0xB5, 0x88, 0x2C, 0xE1, 0xC3, 0x4F, 0x2B, 0x56, 0x36, 0xD7, 0xE3, 0x22, 0x5E, 0x3B, 0x34,
                   0x5D, 0x33, 0xD6, 0x7F, 0xEC, 0x1C, 0x2D, 0x45, 0x86, 0xFD, 0x14, 0xE6, 0x05, 0x39, 0x07, 0xF9};

unsigned char sig_s[] = {
               0x18, 0x4e, 0xbf, 0xa0, 0x9b, 0xe6, 0xeb, 0x66, 0x42, 0x1f, 0x01, 0x9e, 0xb8, 0xf5, 0xf5, 0x18,
               0x41, 0x34, 0x37, 0xd8, 0x20, 0x6e, 0x1d, 0x69, 0x94, 0x05, 0x15, 0x98, 0xa8, 0x64, 0x90, 0x1e};

unsigned char sig_r[] = {
               0x8c, 0xf0, 0x3e, 0xb2, 0x51, 0x87, 0xb2, 0x5c, 0x78, 0x98, 0x71, 0xd9, 0x57, 0x5b, 0xdf, 0x13,
               0x6e, 0x1c, 0xcd, 0x18, 0xba, 0xee, 0xec, 0x5e, 0xac, 0xbe, 0x95, 0xf1, 0x2f, 0x88, 0xaa, 0xa2};

void hexdump(void* buf, size_t length) {
    unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)buf;
    unsigned char c;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        printf("%04x: ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            if (i + j < length) {
                c = *(p + i + j);
                printf("%02x ", c);
            } else {
                printf("   ");
            }
        }
        printf(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            if (i + j < length) {
                c = *(p + i + j);
                if (c >= 32 && c <= 126) {
                    printf("%c", c);
                } else {
                    printf(".");
                }
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        i += 16;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   unsigned char *sig_ptr;
   char *s_r, *s_s;
   int param, msg_len, sig_len;
   unsigned char message[256];
   unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH], signature_der[256];

   EC_GROUP *g;
   EC_POINT *p;
   EC_KEY  *k;
   SHA256_CTX sha256;
   ECDSA_SIG* ec_sig = ECDSA_SIG_new();

   OPENSSL_init_ssl(OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_SSL_STRINGS, NULL);
   OPENSSL_init_crypto(OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_CRYPTO_STRINGS, NULL);

   // seed the random number generator
   srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

   //Some initialization works
   k = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
   EC_KEY_set_conv_form(k, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED);
   g = EC_KEY_get0_group(k);
   p = EC_POINT_new(g);

   //Load EC points
   if (1 != EC_POINT_oct2point(g, p, pub_key_raw, 65, NULL)){
       printf("EC_POINT_oct2point failed:\n");
       printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
   }

   //Set EC public key
   if (1 != EC_KEY_set_public_key(k, p)){
       printf("EC_KEY_set_public_key failed:\n");
       printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
   }
   //Check EC public key
   if (1 != EC_KEY_check_key(k)) {
       printf("EC_KEY_check_key failed:\n");
       printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
   }
   else {
       printf("Public key verified OK\n");
   }

   printf(" Page Data:   "); 
   for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
       printf("%02X", usr_page3[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
   hexdump(usr_page3, 32);
   printf("\n Challenge:   "); 
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    printf("%02X",challenge[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
   hexdump(challenge, 8);


   // ROM NO
   msg_len = 0;
   memcpy(&message[msg_len],rom_id,8);
   msg_len += 8;
   // Page Data
   memcpy(&message[msg_len], usr_page3, 32);
   msg_len += 32;
   // Challenge (Buffer)
   memcpy(&message[msg_len], challenge, 32);
   msg_len += 32;
   // Page#
   message[msg_len++] = 3;//
   // MANID
   memcpy(&message[msg_len], man_id, 2);
   msg_len += 2;

   // Calculate Hash 
   SHA256_Init(&sha256);
   SHA256_Update(&sha256, message, strlen(message));
   SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);

   if (NULL == BN_bin2bn((unsigned char*)sig_r, 32, ECDSA_SIG_get0_r(ec_sig))) {
       printf("BN_bin2bn for r failed:\n");
       printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
   }
 
   if (NULL == BN_bin2bn((unsigned char*)sig_s, 32, ECDSA_SIG_get0_s(ec_sig))) {
       printf("BN_bin2bn for s failed:\n");
       printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
   }

   s_r = BN_bn2hex(ECDSA_SIG_get0_r(ec_sig));
   s_s = BN_bn2hex(ECDSA_SIG_get0_s(ec_sig));
   printf("(sig->r, sig->s): (%s,%s)\n", s_r, s_s);

   sig_ptr = signature_der;
   sig_len = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(ec_sig, &sig_ptr);
   printf("converted signature length = %d\n", sig_len);

   // Validate ECDSA signature
   if (1 != ECDSA_verify(0, hash, sizeof(hash), signature_der, sig_len, k)) {
       printf("ECDSA_verify failed:\n");
       printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
       printf("Signature:\n");
       hexdump(signature_der, sizeof(signature_der));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminarily, you compute your hash incorrectly. First you (try to) copy 32 bytes from `challenge` which contains only 8 bytes. Technically this is Undefined Behavior and the implementation is permitted to do anything, including destroy the Earth -- but most don't; in practice the usual result is either to crash or to use garbage data, and since you didn't observe a crash here, your implementation probably did the latter. Second you then use `strlen(message)` as the length of your data, but it isn't, because the garbage from `challenge` per above probably contains a null byte, and if not, `man_id` certainly does.

However this would only cause the signature verification to fail, not the symptoms you are asking about. For them:

```
    ECDSA_SIG* ec_sig = ECDSA_SIG_new();
...
   if (NULL == BN_bin2bn((unsigned char*)sig_r, 32, ECDSA_SIG_get0_r(ec_sig))) {
       printf("BN_bin2bn for r failed:\n");
       printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
   }
```

This creates a new ECDSA_SIG object, but no actual signature, so its R and S fields are empty (null). When you call _get0_r it simply returns the field without checking, and BN_bin2bn(buffer,len,null) *creates a new BN object* to contain the number which it returns (as a pointer) but you immediately discard. In short, this does NOT put the R value in ec_sig.

```
   if (NULL == BN_bin2bn((unsigned char*)sig_s, 32, ECDSA_SIG_get0_s(ec_sig))) {
       printf("BN_bin2bn for s failed:\n");
       printf("%s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
   }
```

Ditto for S.

```
   s_r = BN_bn2hex(ECDSA_SIG_get0_r(ec_sig));
   s_s = BN_bn2hex(ECDSA_SIG_get0_s(ec_sig));
   printf("(sig->r, sig->s): (%s,%s)\n", s_r, s_s);
```

If you do this, it tries to treat the null pointers still in ec_sig as BN objects and print them, but as null pointers are not actual objects it crashes.

```
   sig_ptr = signature_der;
   sig_len = i2d_ECDSA_SIG(ec_sig, &sig_ptr);
```

If you do this (and not the previous), it tries to encode a "signature" that is not actually a signature, producing the bogus 2-byte encoding you observed.

You should instead do something like:

```
    ECDSA_SIG *ec_sig = ECDSA_SIG_new();
    BN *rbn = BN_bin2bn(rval,sizeof(rval),NULL); 
    BN *sbn = BN_bin2bn(sval,sizeof(sval),NULL);
    // best style is to check and handle if r and/or s is NULL
    // but these calls can't actually fail in any sane system
    (void) ECDSA_SIG_set0(ec_sig,rbn,sbn); 
    // again you can check for return value != 1, but it won't happen
```

and of course correct the hash computation.

Aside: when passing an `unsigned char []` variable (like your `sig_r` or `sig_s`) to a `const unsigned char *` parameter (like `BN_bin2bn` takes) you don't need a cast: any occurrence of an lvalue with type `[qualified] array of T` other than as the operand of `sizeof offsetof _Alignof` 'decays' (is automatically converted) to `pointer to [qualified] T`, and any pointer to  unqualified T can automatically 'add' qualification `const` and/or `volatile`. Thus `sig_r` with type `unsigned char[32]` automatically becomes `unsigned char *` and then `const unsigned char *` as needed. This is extremely basic to programming in C (and the 'C subset' of C++, if you don't switch entirely to `std::vector` and the like) and should be covered within the first two weeks of any course, or two chapters of any text.

Comment: Thanks for your instructions. ECDSA_SIG_set0() is indeed the correct API to make it working for me. Hash length was also an issue that I missed.